# make <ul> center vertically by bootstrap

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, frontend, bootstrap-5

I have this div that is parent for ul. I tried to make  ul center vertically but I do not know why I see this situation:
[image]

```
<div className=" d-flex align-items-center bg-primary  ">
            <ul
              className="d-flex align-items-center bg-success"
              style={{ gap: "3em" }}
            >
              <li className="bg-danger">vision</li>
              <li>consorzio</li>
              <li>contatti</li>
            </ul>
          </div>
```

the bg-success  is not got centered in bg-primary div.

Comment: Try adding `{margin: 0}` on the `<ul>` element. Likely the default margin-bottom on the `<ul>` created a visual offset.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally `ul` elements by default have margin you should remove it first :

global.css

```
ul {
   margin : 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```html
<div className="d-flex align-items-center bg-primary">
  <ul className="d-flex align-items-center bg-success justify-content-center" style={{ gap: "3em" }}>
    <li className="bg-danger">vision</li>
    <li>consorzio</li>
    <li>contatti</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```